# SSH Git without having to type in my password every time

Tags: git, terminal

I have a git repo set up on my website which can be accessed by ssh, but every time I push some files to the repo I have to type in my password again. Is there a way in which I only have to type my password in once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to put your SSH public key on your server, in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

You can find your public key on your local machine, in the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file (supposing you are on a Unix system, I don't know the location of this key on Windows).

Comment: If your private key is password-protected (it should), this won't prevent asking for a password.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into ssh keys.

Some instructions:

http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/

http://oreilly.com/pub/h/66